# Log4j2 regular expressions

Tags: java, regex, configuration, log4j2

I am working with the log4j2 configuration file settings to try and make the config file use regular expressions so the it can use multiple classes in the logger property and name attribute. This is what I have tried so far that doesn't appear to work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN" monitorInterval="30">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd 'at' HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
        <File name="ERROR_FILE" fileName="../log/error.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd 'at' HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </File>
        <File name="EVENT_FILE" fileName="../log/event.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd 'at' HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="foo.test" level="trace"
            additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Logger>       
        <Logger name="foo.*" level="debug"
            additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="ERROR_FILE" level="ERROR"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="EVENT_FILE" level="INFO"/>
        </Logger>       
        <Root level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Has anybody ever been able to successfully use regular expressions or even globs in the log4j2 config file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out I do not need to put regular expressions at all in the package name. For example if in my foo package i had foo.bar, foo.foo, and foo.test. I would put foo in the Logger property name attribute to log the ERROR and INFO level logs from any any of 3 packages that begins with foo as such.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN" monitorInterval="30">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd 'at' HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
        <File name="ERROR_FILE" fileName="../log/error.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd 'at' HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </File>
        <File name="EVENT_FILE" fileName="../log/event.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd 'at' HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="foo.test" level="trace"
            additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Logger>       
        <Logger name="foo" level="debug"
            additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="ERROR_FILE" level="ERROR"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="EVENT_FILE" level="INFO"/>
        </Logger>       
        <Root level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```